# How do I filter a list by existance of an attribute in ansible/jinja2?

Tags: filter, ansible, jinja2

G'day everyone.

I have two ansible tasks like this, running over the 'workernodes' group in the inventory file:

```
- name: count remote files 
  find:
    paths: "{{ data_path }}"
  register: exported_files

- name: sum up number of remote files
  set_fact: 
    sum_of_exported_files: "{{ groups[ workernodes ] | map('extract', hostvars, 'exported_files') | map(attribute='matched') | sum }}"
  run_once: yes
```

This works fine as long as all are nodes available. But if the find-Task count not run on any of the workernodes i get in error in the sum-up task. There is no exported_files variable on for this node, so the mapping to the attribute fails.

How can i filter for the existance of the exported_files attribute in the extarcted hostvars list?

Please EnlightMe

Thanks.

Comment: Does the error occur on `| map(attribute='matched')` or on `| sum`?

Comment: It happens on the map-clause, because the previous task is not able to fill this variable for the host if the host is down or not reachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G'day everyone,

finally i found the (really simple) answer by myself:

```
sum_of_exported_files: "{{ groups[ workernodes ] | map('extract', hostvars, 'exported_files') | select("defined") | map(attribute='matched') | select("number") | sum }}"
```

Thanks isabellema for your thought that helped me to think it over.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding this `when:` clause:

```
when: groups[ workernodes ] | map('extract', hostvars, 'exported_files')|list|first|length > 0"
```